# Gibt es Ideen oder Vorschläge für eine elegantere geschlechtsneutrale Form als das angehängte "In" wie in "BürgerInnen"?

Tags: noun, gender

Vielleicht geht es anderen TeilnehmerInnen dieser Plattform wie mir: ich möchte mich häufig in Wort und Schrift auf beide Geschlechter beziehen (und am liebsten auch die diversen anderen biologischen und gesellschaftlichen Zwischen- und Extremformen nicht ausgrenzen) und verwende eine der folgenden Möglichkeiten:

- Das besagte "In"- oder "Innen"-Suffix ggf. in Kombination mit "dIE TeilnehmerIn"
- Ein "/in"- oder "/innen"-Suffix ggf. in Kombination mit "die/der Teilnehmer/in"
- Eine neutrale Formulierung wie "die Teilnehmenden" oder "die teilnehmende Person"
- Weibliche und männliche Formen zufällig gemischt (in der IT-Literatur ist derlei manchmal zu finden, etwa "... wenn die Systemadministratorin dem Programmierer das Update nahelegt..." (besonders in amerikanischen Publikationen werden "she" und "he" oft angenehm gleich verteilt)
- Einen Fußnoten-Hinweis, etwa "Aus Gründen des Leseflusses verwende ich stets die männliche Form, gemeint sind aber immer alle beide, außer wenn..."

Gibt es Ideen oder Vorschläge, die über obige Aufzählung hinaus weisen? Oder sieht jefraut gar die Möglichkeit, dass sich das "evolutionär" ändert (durch immer häufiger angewandte Anglizismen zum Beispiel)?

Comment: Evolutionär wäre es, wenn man begriffe, daß "Liebe Studenten ..." genau so viele Leute anspricht wie "Liebe Studierende ..."

Comment: @Ingo: "Studierende" bezeichnet aber Leute, die im Moment studieren - ob diese Student sind oder nicht, und bezeichnet Studenten, die im Moment nicht studieren, sondern essen oder schlafen, nicht.

Comment: related: [Vorschläge für männliche Movierung?](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/25093/vorschläge-für-männliche-movierung)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Ich glaube, es ist jedem Beteiligten besser getan, wenn man sich darauf besinnt, dass die männliche Form *per conventionem* zur Verallgemeinerung verwendet wird.

Anstatt zu versuchen, Leute dadurch zu integrieren, dass wir eine völlig unnatürliche Sprache verwenden, sollten wir uns lieber daran gewöhnen, **daran zu denken**, dass in der verallgemeinerten Form viel mehr Leute mit eingeschlossen sind, als wir anfänglich und unwissend angenommen haben.

Die Anwesenheit der vormals ausgeschlossenen Leute muss in unseren Köpfen normal werden. Wenn wir eine für uns unnatürliche Sprache verwenden, werden die Leute, über die wir damit sprechen, auf ewig genauso fremd und seltsam bleiben.

Comment: +1 Und ich habe kein Problem damit, wenn ich mich gleichzeitig als **die** Person, **der** Mensch und **das** Kind meiner Eltern bezeichne.

Comment: Das ist keine Antwort auf die Frage, sondern eine reine Meinungsäußerung.

Comment: Was ist mir "wir anfänglich" gemeint? Die Indogermanen? Anfänglich hat überhaupt niemand bezweifelt, dass die generische Form generisch ist. Bei "Mitglied, Person u.a." bezweifelt es bis heute keiner. Es ist ideologische Propaganda so zu tun, als sei die generische Form spezifisch männlich.

Comment: -1, Statt einer wilden Theorie, was aus heutiger (2011) Sicht besser wäre oder eine unnatürliche Sprache sei, verweise ich auf berühmte Werke, deren Deutsch mir heute jede Deutschlehrerin als "grausig falsch" ankreiden würde: `Wenn ich den Eseln sol folgen, die werden mir die buchstaben furlegen, und also dolmetzschen: Auß dem uberflus des hertzen redet der mund. Sage mir, Ist das deutsch geredt? Welcher deutscher verstehet solchs? Was ist uberflus des hertzen fur ein ding? Das kan kein deutscher sagen,` (http://www.stefanjacob.de/Geschichte/Unterseiten/Textproben.php?Multi=56)

Answer (score 4):

Ein Vorschlag von Anna Heger zu Pronomen ohne Geschlecht und das De-Le-System "aus dem Netz" (Autor will vorerst anynom bleiben).

**[Xier-Pronomen ohne Geschlecht](https://www.annaheger.de/pronomen/)** (Version 3.3, August 2021)

1. *xier* statt Personalpronomen *sie* und *er*
2. *xies* statt Possesivpronomen *ihr* und *sein*
3. *dier* statt Artikel und Relativpronomen *die* und *der*

Personal- und Relativpronomen
[image: Personal- und Relativpronomen]

Possesivpronomen:

- statt *sein* und *ihr* Verwendung von *xies* mit den bekannten Endungen -s, -se, -sem, -sen, -ses. Für geschlechtslos stattdessen ein Vokal, Vorschlag is *a*

Beispielsätze  Wortstamm xies_:

- Nom.:

  - Xiesa Freund_in, xiese Freundin, xies Freund und xies Kind schreiben.
  - Meina Freund_in und eura Freund_in schreiben.
- Gen.:

  - Xier schämt sich xiesas Freund_in, xieser Freundin, xieses Freundes und xieses Kindes.
  - Du schämst dich meinas Freund_in und euras Freund_ins.
- Dat.:

  - Das gehört xiesam Freund_in, xieser Freundin, xiesem Freund und xiesem Kind.
  - Das gehört meinam Freund_in und deinam Freund_in.
- Akk.:

  - Xier sucht xiesan Freund_in;, xiese Freundin, xiesen Freund und xies Kind.
  - Wir suchen ihran Freund_in und unseran Freund_in.

Es ist ersichtlich, dass es bei dem Vorschlag von Anna Heger nur um den Teil vor einem Substantiv geht, die gegenderten Endungen sind mit dem Unterstrich _ versehen.

Anna Heger listet auch [Beispiele](https://www.annaheger.de/darunterdarueber/#ausschnitte), wo xier & Co bereits in Untertiteln verwendet werden (*O*riginal, *U*ntertitel und *S*ynchronisierung)

- *Star Trek Discovery* (Staffel 3, Episode 8, 43:30, Netflix, 2020, Untertitel von Tanja Mushenko, Synchronisierung von Arena Synchron.)

  - (O): Nothing more to do until their algorithm finishes. No let them sleep. At that age, whatever they can get is golden. Gray stopped speaking to them.
  - (U): Wir warten auf deren Algorithmus. Nein. Lass *dey* schlafen. In dem Alter ist das so wichtig. Gray redet nicht mehr mit dem.
  - (S): Wir müssen jetzt warten bis *deyren* Algorithmus fertig rechnet. Nein nein nein nein nein, lass dey bitte schlafen. In diesem Alter brauchen sie jede Sekunde. Gray hat aufgehört mit denen zu reden.
- *Transparent* (Staffel 4, Episode 9, 19:30, Sky Atlantic, 2017, Untertitel von ?, Synchronisierung von Arena Synchron.)

  - (O): Ali is not here or maybe ditching us because of their gender? Which would be very they.
  - (U): Ali ist also nicht hier oder versetzt uns wegen *xiesem* Geschlecht was typisch für *xien* wäre.
  - (S): Ali ist nicht hier, oder womöglich versetzt *xier* uns, wegen *xies* Geschlechts. Das wär typisch *xier*.

**Das [De-Le-System](https://delesystem.wordpress.com/ausfuehrliche-beschreibung-des-de-le-systems/)** "[aus dem Netz](https://delesystem.wordpress.com)". Es versucht sich darin, neben den direkten Artikeln alle möglichen männlich-weiblich-Differenzierungen zu addressieren:

- zentrale Bausteine sind  Artikel "de" und Pronomen "le"
- Pronomen "le" dekliniert: *lein, lir, lich* (für mein/dein, mir/dir, mich/dich)
- Singular im Utrum durch -e
- Plural im Utrum durch -n
- Ausnahmen
- Zusatz "j": enden heute männliche Substantive auf -e und die weiblichen Pendants auf -in, dann wäre -je möglich: *der Russe & die Russin => de Russje*
- Verschmelzung: sind die Worte an sich geschlechtsbezogen: wie Tochter/ Sohn => *de Sochte* oder *Gatte/ Gattin => de Gattje*
- Einschränkungen (zu "ist anders"):
- gelegentlich identische Wortgestaltung zu heute (*de Deutsche, des Deutschen, der Deutschen, den Deutschen*)

  - *die Studenten => die Studentjen*
- Substantive, die keine Personen bezeichnen (Tisch, Buch): hier müsste sich zeigen, was sich durchsetzt

Idee:

> Die Idee hinter dem De-Le-System ist es, neue Ausdrucksmöglichkeiten für die geschlechtsneutrale Benennung von Personen einzuführen, um es jenen Deutschsprachigen, die sich in manchen Kontexten gerne geschlechtsneutral ausdrücken wollen, zu ermöglichen, dies auf eine Weise zu tun, die auch in der gesprochenen Sprache problemlos funktioniert.

Beispiel anhand [Rotkäppchen](https://delesystem.wordpress.com/rotkaeppchen-geschlechtsneutral/):

> Es war einmal eine kleine süße Kind, den hatte jede lieb, de lich nur ansah, am allerliebsten aber leine Großelter, de wusste gar nicht was le der Kind alles geben sollte. Einmal schenkte le lir ein Käppchen von rotem Sammet, und weil lir das so wohl stand, und le nichts anderes mehr tragen wollte, hieß le nur das Rotkäppchen. Eines Tages sprach leine Elter zu lir „komm, Rotkäppchen, da hast du ein Stück Kuchen und eine Flasche Wein, bring das der Großelter hinaus; le ist krank und schwach und wird sich daran erfreuen. Mach dich auf bevor es heiß wird, und wenn du hinaus kommst, so geh hübsch sittsam und lauf nicht vom Weg ab, sonst fällst du und zerbrichst das Glas und de Großelter hat nichts. Und wenn du in leine Stube kommst, so vergiss nicht guten Morgen zu sagen und guck nicht erst in alle Ecken herum.

Hier noch zwei Tabellen von der Einstiegs-Erklär-Seite. Insgesamt findet sich dort auch eine Betrachtung von Lösungen in anderen Sprachen und warum diese/ jene Auswahl bisher erfolgte.

Ob dies eleganter ist als andere Ansätze, vermag ich nicht zu bewerten.

[image: Gegenüberstellung mask-/fem-/neut-/utrum]

[image: ein Beispiel anhand "Lehrerin"]

Answer (score 3):

Inwiefern Anglizismen helfen sollen, sehe ich nicht. Der master of business art ist auch ein Er, oder? Nur ein sächliches Geschlecht fehlt der englischen Sprache.

Mir ist im Computerbereich aufgefallen, wie ich dazu neige, als Beispiel für Personen, die keine Ahnung haben, spontan zu alten Frauen zu greifen, und wiewohl ich derartige Klischees nicht selbst weitertragen will, so erwarte ich davon sehr, sehr wenig.

Gegen die Medienindustrie kommt man nicht an.

Und sprachlich ist es oft ein Getue. Man lenkt von seinem eigentlichen Inhalt ab, und die Leute thematisieren dann das Binnen-I. Das kommt für mich meist nicht in Betracht. Es verwirrt und funktioniert so nicht.

Es gibt so viele Beispiele für Euphemismen, dass ich mir sehr gut eine Welt vorstellen kann, in der man von Putzmännern und Programmiererinnen redet, und die Wirklichkeit ist diametral umgekehrt.

Bemerkenswert finde ich die Behauptung der Frage, dass „die teilnehmende Person“ neutraler sein soll als „der Teilnehmer“, dabei ist „der Teilnehmer“ ebenso wenig festlegend wie diese Alternative – es ist eine falsche Symmetrieerwartung, die davon ausgeht, dass der weiblichen Teilnehmerin eine maskuline Form gegenüberstehen muss, bei der dann Frauen nur zweitrangig mit gemeint sind. Dabei ist Teilnehmer immer neutral – nur Kontextwissen kann die Teilnehmer zur reinen Männergruppe machen, dann ist es aber der Kontext und nicht das Wort, das die Information transportiert.

Außerdem sind die ~enden-Konstruktionen abzulehnen, weil sie falsch sind. „Busfahrer dürfen keinen Alkohol trinken“ bedeutet etwas radikal anderes als „Die Busfahrenden dürfen keinen Alkohol trinken“ – nicht immer ist das Beispiel so klar.

Comment: Stimmt, der Artikel wird auch vor importierten Berufsbezeichnungen im Singular männlich bleiben - aber der Plural hätte sich immerhin erledigt, wie wir StackExchange Participants einsehen müssen. Dass die gestelzt geschlechtsneutrale Sprache oft eine komische Note enthält oder eher eine Wunschwirklichkeit ausdrückt - klar. Dennoch wünsche ich mir, das auch im Deutschen irgendwie ausdrücken zu können...

Comment: Dafür erben wir dann wohl einen Sack Deppen Leer Zeichen.

Comment: @Olaf: Selten sieht man übrigens Bemühungen um Geschlechtsneutrale Sprache wenn es um Verbrecherinnen, Diebinnen, Mörderinnen und Steuerhinterzieherinnen geht.

Answer (score 2):

[Thomas Kronschläger](https://www.tu-braunschweig.de/germanistik/abt/did/mitarb/kronschlaeger)<sup>(Vortrag u.a. 04/18)</sup> beschreibt ein System zum "Entgendern", also der Unsichtbarmachung & Neutralisierung von (biologischen) Geschlechtsmerkmalen.

Neutrale Grundworte sind ebenfalls das Ziel von Luisa F. Pusch, Ausführung unter dem Beispieltext von Kronschläger.

Das System Phettberg wird seit 1992 durch Hermes [Phettberg](https://www.phettberg.at/) in der Wochenzeitung "Falter" benutzt. Der es nach eigener Aussage in der anarchistischen Szene Wiens aufgeschnappt hat.

- Kurzfassung beim [Deutschlandfunk Kultur](https://www.deutschlandfunkkultur.de/entgendern-nach-hermes-phettberg-bis-das-arzty-kommt.1013.de.html?dram:article_id=492876)
- beschrieben bei [Liebchen+Liebchen](https://blog.lplusl.de/nebenbei/gendern-nach-phettberg/)
- Abstract bei [researchgate](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/343974830_Entgendern_nach_Phettberg_im_Uberblick)

**Das System Phettberg nach Kronschläger (Vollzitat u.a. von [l+l](https://blog.lplusl.de/nebenbei/gendern-nach-phettberg/)):**

*Genus*

> Alle Personenbezeichnungen, die nach Phettberg entgendert werden, sind im Genus Neutrum (ne utrum = keines von beidem), daher ist es das Arzty, das Lesy, das Wirty etc.

*Bildung grundsätzlich*

- Singular: Stamm + y
- Plural: Stamm +ys

*Bildung detailliert*

- Bei Wörtern, die das -er verwenden, um zu Personenbezeichnungen zu werden (movierte Wörter), ersetzt das -y das -er: Bäcker_in: das Bäcky.
- Bei Wörtern, die nicht in -er enden, wird das -y angehängt: Professor_in: Professory.
- Im Plural werden Wörter, die für die Pluralbildung umgelautet werden, weiterhin umgelautet: Koch -> Köche : das Kochy -> die Köchys
- Arzt -> Ärzte : das Arzty -> die Ärztys

*Pronomina*

- Die Verwendung von Pronomina im Fließtext erfolgt wie bei jedem anderen Neutrum auch:

  - In seiner Arbeit stellt das Linguisty vor…
- Ich [Kronschläger] empfehle allerdings im schriftlichen Gebrauch das Beistellen eines (n.), um etwaige Unklarheiten auszuräumen und eindeutig kein Geschlecht anzukategorisieren:

  - In seinem(n.) neuen Buch schlägt Müller vor…

*Besonderheiten*

- Es gibt, soweit bislang ersichtlich, nur einen Sonderfall: Personenbezeichnungen auf -ling

  - Der Widerling: das Widerly / der Lehrling: das Lehrly
- Auch wenn es vielleicht nicht dringend nötig erscheint, diese Wörter zu entgendern, ist es das meines Erachtens vor allem im Singular, wenn gezeigt werden soll, dass das Geschlecht nicht bedeutend ist.

*Bezüglich /man/:*

- Phettberg verwendet dieses Wort nicht, ich [Kronschläger] empfehle ebenfalls, es nicht zu verwenden, da es eindeutig geschlechtliche Assoziationen hervorruft. Für eine detaillierte, auch formale Begründung siehe Pober, M. 2007: Gendersymmetrie. Überlegungen zur geschlechtersymmetrischen Struktur eines Genderwörterbuches im Deutschen. Würzburg: Königshausen & Neumann.

*Zielwörter*

Entgendert werden ausschließlich Personenbezeichnungen, also Wörter, die verwendet werden, um auf Personen zu verweisen. Ob im Wort auch entgendert werden soll, sei den Sprechys und Schreibys selbst überlassen (Bürgersteig/Bürgysteig, Bürgermeisty/Bürgymeisty). Das ist zugleich auch ein großer Vorteil des Entgenderns nach Phettberg: das -y wird, wenn diese Form breitere Verwendung findet, eindeutig als Personenbezeichnung erkannt: das Drucky ist also eine Person, die den Beruf der Drucker_in ausübt, der Drucker ist dann eindeutig das Gerät.

*Dosis*

Je nach Geschmack und Meinung des Verwendys kann voll entgendert werden, (also auch bei Personen, deren Geschlecht vermeintlich bekannt ist, das Bloggy Frank Müller) oder nur dann, wenn dem(n.) Verwendy die Person unbekannt ist (Das Fahry im Wagen vor mir fährt seltsam). Im Plural würde ich immer entgendern.

(/Vollzitat Ende)

Fiktives Textbeispiel von Kronschläger, via [researchgate](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/343974830_Entgendern_nach_Phettberg_im_Uberblick)

> Studentys, die regelmäßig im Hörsaal sitzen, werden als aufmerksamer und leistungsbereiter wahrgenommen als jene ihrer Kommilitonys, die von zuhause aus arbeiten. Dieser Umstand ist Professorys und anderen Dozentys bereits lange bekannt, wird aber in der konkreten Situation nicht immer reflektiert. Es hat sich also für alle, die ein geisteswissenschaftliches
> Studium betreiben, bewährt, regelmäßig die Vorlesung als Hörys zu besuchen und Frage zu stellen. Dass hier allerdings ein blinder Fleck was Betreuungspflichten anbelangt, vorherrscht, hat das Sozialwissenschaftly A. M. bereits 2011 in seinem(n.) Paper TITEL herausgearbeitet.
> Es hat weiters festgestellt, dass die Notengrad nicht signifikant davon abhängt, aber durchaus die Einschätzung der Kompetenz der Studentys. Besonders bei Studienrichtungen, die eine hohe sozialen Bedeutung haben, wie zum Beispiel die Ausbildung zukünftiger Lehrys, wäre es aber wichtig, diese Komponente, das Pflegen von Angehörigen, von Freundys etc. als Teil
> der Sozialkompetenz zu begreifen und das nicht zu bestrafen. gerade weil diese Personen in Zukunft mit Schülys arbeiten, sind aber Sozialkompetenzen und v. a. das Wissen um familiäre Betreuungsarbeit besonders wichtig. Da diese Faktoren aber von den Prüflys in Klausurensituationen nicht erfasst werden können, haben es Studentys, die von zuhause aus arbeiten, nicht immer leicht.

Das referenzierte Buch zur Gendersymmetrie von Maria Pober:

- beim Verlag [Königshausen & Neumann](https://www.verlag-koenigshausen-neumann.de/product_info.php/info/p5757_Gendersymmetrie---berlegungen-zur-geschlechtersymmetrischen-Struktur-eines-Genderw--rterbuchs-im-Deutschen-----58-00.html)
- bei [Google Books](https://books.google.ws/books?id=0C9kK1htV9kC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_vpt_reviews#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Den **gleichen Ansatz der neutralen Grundworte** als insgesamtes Ziel ist auch in diesem [Interview](https://www.jetzt.de/hauptsache-gendern/gendern-linguistin-luise-f-pusch-ueber-das-gendersternchen-und-geschlechtergerechte-sprache) mit [Luise F. Pusch](https://www.fembio.org/biographie.php/frau/biographieforschung/zur-person-luise-f-pusch/) diskutiert:

- Vorschlag 1: statt Gendersternchen und Binnen-I stattdessen das Sternchen auf dem I

  - technische Übergangslösung: das Ausrufezeichen wie bei "P!nk"
- Vorschlag 2: Männer reden im generischen Maskulinum, Frauen reden im generischen Femininum
- Zielzustand

  - eine neutrale Form ohne Suffix
  - eine männliche, eine weibliche und eine non-binäre

Der Glottisschlag ist u.a. eine [Idee von ihr](https://www.genderleicht.de/luise-f-pusch-und-der-genderstern/) von 1985/1986. Im Interview bei jetzt verweist Pusch u.a. auf Matthias Behlert, der eine Version von geschlechtergerechtem Deutsch entwickelte und dies 1998 an [Grimms Märchen demonstrierte](https://www.pauker.at/VIP/Matti/kate_de/2754). Podcast mit Matthias Behlert zum Thema bei [untergrund-blättle.ch](https://www.untergrund-bl%C3%A4ttle.ch/audio/518581/ein-interview-mit-matthias-behlert-zu-geschlechtergerechter-sprache.html).

Answer (score 1):

Ich muss mich doch sehr wundern (mit Augenzwinkern).

Erstens sind obige Formulierungen doch sehr "unzeitgemäß", (die Anführungszeichen sind bewusst):

Der **Gender-star** kam bisher gar nicht vor.

Hier mal ein Link dazu, nicht aus besonderem Grund ausgewählt, nur weil er den Konflikt aufzeigt: http://www.spiegel.de/politik/deutschland/die-gruenen-machen-geschlechtsneutrale-sprache-zur-pflicht-a-1063228.html

Also politisch am korrektesten wäre also:

> **Student*innen** mit Stern

**Geschlechtsspezifische Ansprache** finde ich übrigens die bessere Bezeichnung, vor allem, wenn man noch "die/der" verwendet, zumal das genderneutral gar nicht mehr geht, weil die Sprache dafür keinen Artikel hat Oder "das?"- ehrlich? Geschlechtsneutral wäre für mich die Nichtbetonung des Trennenden statt die Suche danach.

> **Student*en**

wäre neutral, aber es hat sowas wie- ein Kompromiss, aber es nützt keiner Seite, und die oben genannte Kritik der falschen Betonung trifft ähnlich zu.

-- Disclaimer --
Ja, ich erlaube mir im Folgenden auch über Hintergründe statt nur über das Wie einer "korrekten" Ansprache zu diskutieren, weil ich finde, dass beides nicht trennbar ist:

Folgende Gründe für die Antwort, so wie sie ist (es muss nicht jeder zu Ende lesen. Deswegen hier die Warnung.).
-- Disclaimer --

**Wenn * sich nicht diskriminiert fühlt, fühlt sich * auch von einer Ansprache in "gewohnter" oder üblicher Sprache angesprochen und es ist keine gesonderte Ansprache vonnöten.**

**In der Überbetonung sexueller Identität wie durch viele vermeintlich politisch korrekte Anreden meines Erachtens vorliegend, liegt eine Diskriminierung vieler anderer Identitäten, insbesondere solcher, die in der Anrede nicht herausgestellt werden.**

Ich kann zwar besser verstehen, dass sich z.B. transsexuelle und intersexuelle Menschen allgemein in unserer Gesellschaft benachteiligt fühlen, nachdem ich  welche kennengelernt habe, aber bei der Anrede handelt es sich meiner Meinung nach um eine Betonung des Falschen: Wenn ich einen beruflichen Vortrag halte, dann ist die sexuelle Identität unwesentlich. Folgerichtig müsste man zusätzlich noch die sexuelle Orientierung beimischen, obwohl es in der Sprache dafür gar keine Anrede gibt, und da möchte man ausrufen:

Und das ist auch gut so !

Ja, das stimmt doch. Wenn man so anfängt, dann würde ich bitteschön doch auch zuvorderst die homosexuellen Menschen begrüßen. Finde ich aber zu vereinfacht: Was ist mit den Menschen, die Frauen lieben, mit Männern lieber Sex haben, mit ihren Eltern kuscheln, mit Männern saufen, und wiederum andere Vorlieben, mit Schwulen gern Shoppen, über Lesben gerne Videos schauen, und andere Dinge wiederum mit ganz anderen Gruppierungen vorziehen? Und vielleicht lieber heute Mann sind, und auch als solcher angesprochen werden wollen, morgen aber lieber als Frau? Gibt es nicht? Da widerspreche ich!)

Ich habe doch viele Identitäten- s. "I'm a bitch. I'm a lover. I'm a child. I'm a mother. I'm a sinner. I'm a saint." Na gut, biologisch stimmt "mother" bei mir jetzt weniger, aber von einem sozialen Standpunkt der 50er Jahre kommt's auch hin, ich bin "Elter".

Bevor wir nachher also die Schwulen Machos, die Lesbischen Veganer, die Rauchenden Laktoseintoleranten alle einzeln anreden müssen, oder sogar noch groß schreiben, bevor die pansexuellen Intersexuellen mit den pansexuellen Homosexuellen nicht gemeinsam erwähnt werden wollen, wenn es bei der Veranstaltung aber z.B. um die Einführung einer Tempo-30-Zone im Wohngebiet geht- müssen wir meines Erachtens einhalten! Sex doesn't matter (here).

An der Fernuni Hagen wurde 2016 die Diskussion über das, was ich geschlechtspezifische Ansprache nenne, in der, quasi, Studierendenzeitung, wieder geführt- ich hatte echt gedacht, man könne sich mal um wichtige Diskriminierungen kümmern, s.u., die meisten StudentInnen werden später nicht zu den Unterprivilegierten der Gesellschaft gehören- wenn überhaupt je.

Ich vertrete die Ansicht- und viel wichtiger, ich kann sie auch begründen- dass **weniger Verkrampfung** das Wichtigste für die Gleichberechtigung aller ist, alle Formen, die dazu beitragen, empfinde ich als positiv, dazu zählen, z.B.:

> - Formulierungen, die klarstellen, dass es nicht (immer) notwendig ist, zwischen Geschlechtern zu unterscheiden, wenn es eben nicht notwendig ist. Denn dies ist für mich das Gegenteil einer modernen Gesellschaft, in der Frauen insb. einer immer stärkere Rolle spielen.
> - Äußerungen und Formulierungen, die **nicht-missionarisch** sind, sondern auf eigener Entscheidung beruhen, z.B. eine Fußnote, durchgängig die weibliche Form zu verwenden, usw. s.o.
> - zufällige Mischung, wie in der Frage genannt hat Vorteile auf beiden "Meinungslagern"
> - Wer unbedingt Anrede an sexuelle Identität knüpfen möchte, gerne mal ausschließliche Verwendung der weiblichen Form, jedenfalls lieber als Varianten, die ich als Sprachfaschismus empfinde, wenn es zum Zwang für Alle werden soll.
> - Sarkastische oder politisch **augenzwinkernd**e oder überraschende Verwendung, z.B. "die Programmiererin", "das Student", "der Bundeskanzler, Frau Merkel"
> - Weiteres Beispiel: Ich war auf einer recht speziellen IT-Konferenz mit über 200 Teilnehmern, begrüßt wurde (und dann begründet) mit: "Sehr geehrte Dame, sehr geehrte Herren". Das passt, da wird auch jedem klar, da müsste sich was ändern.

Die ausdrückliche Nennung des Weiblichen sollte man dafür generell betonen, wenn es Sinn macht, gerne auch politisch. Z.B. In der Programmierung bzw. Graphentheorie gibt es oft Kind-/Eltern-Knoten. In manchen Artikeln wird auch Vater-Knoten verwendet, z.B. http://www.enzyklo.de/Begriff/Elternknoten
Ich las mal einen Leserbrief einer Informatikerin, die darauf hinwies, das wäre biologisch eher schwach, Tochter-/Mutterknoten wäre besser, denn nur: *Mater certa est*.
Das gefällt! *Da* hat es Stil, Sprachgebräuche zu ändern, gerne die weibliche Form zu wählen statt der neutralen.

**Wichtig an der Diskussion finde ich Folgendes zu erwähnen:**

Ich sehe in Deutschland einen Reflex alles zu glauben, was in gewissen Kreisen behauptet wird, ohne es zu hinterfragen. Niemand will diskriminiert sein, aber man und frau muss über den Status weiblicher Diskriminierung 2017 auch nicht alles glauben. Es ist m.E. vor allem mehr Ehrlichkeit nötig. Wenn * sich über den gender gap (Vor allem welchen? Was ist mit den lesbischen berufstätigen Müttern, den alleinerziehenden Vätern, was ist gerade, wenn wir beim gender star sind, mit den Transsexuellen im Beruf?) aufregt, der durchaus diskutierenswürdig ist, aber eben mehrdimensionale Ursachen hat und auch solche Erkenntnisbereitschaft und Lösungen fordert, sollte man schon berücksichtigen, ob * z.B. zu den 10% seiner Firma oder der Bevölkerung mit dem höchsten Einkommen gehört oder nicht, und welcher Diskriminierung dann die Anderen unterliegen, egal ob Männer oder Frauen.

Dass in der deutschen Sprache das Weibliche unterrepräsentiert sei, insbesondere unzureichend angesprochen werden, ist z.B. m.E. ein nicht auszurottender Irrtum.

1. Das komplette Plural ist weiblich! Also kann man argumentieren, immer, wenn man "die" Mitarbeiter anspricht, dass man damit NATÜRLICH auch die männlichen, angesprochen sind...
2. Praktisch alles Geld der Welt gehört der Weiblichkeit: Jede Firma ist in Verträgen, auch im Rechtsdeutsch weiblich, nicht nur die "Tochterfirmen". Z.B. steht in jedem Gerichtsprotokoll "die Klägerin", wenn es sich um eine GmbH ("die") oder AG, OHG, etc. handelt !!!
3. Wie schon gesagt: Die (Über)betonung sexuell unterschiedlicher Identitäten, insb. wenn sie permanent in einem Vortrag oder Schriftwerk erfolgt, ist erstens unnütz, weil meist sachfremd, zweitens diskriminierend und unfortschrittlich, weil es **viele andere Identitäten gibt**, und damit in einer demokratisch/freiheitlich/pluralistischen Gesellschaft kontraproduktiv, **weil das Trennende betont wird und nicht das Gemeinsame**. Wenn es bewusst erfolgt, weil es vielleicht Sinn macht, also etwa eine tatsächliche Minderheit begrüßt oder eine Benachteiligung verbalisiert wird, ist es etwas anderes.
4. Wir sind nicht mehr im 20. Jahrhundert und sollten in dem Punkt entspannen: Frauen kommen gewaltig- auch ohne Quote übrigens!
   Wir müssen 2017 nicht mehr die Diskussionen der 80er oder 90er Jahre des letzten Jahrhunderts führen. Frauen haben die besseren Schulabschlüsse, die besseren Hochschulabschlüsse.

Wo, wenn nicht in New York lassen sich Trends ablesen:
https://www.welt.de/wirtschaft/article1244246/Wo-Frauen-mehr-verdienen-als-Maenner.html

Anmerkung am Rande: Mit meinem Schornsteinfeger kam zufällig heute eine weibliche Auszubildende mit. 20 weibliche Azubis in ihrem Jahrgang. Wie ich schon sagte: Dinge ändern sich, Kämpfe der Vergangenheit kann man abschwächen.

Warum spielen berufliche Entwicklungen eine Rolle für die genannte Frage: Weil man doch vielleicht dann die Sprache im Dorf lassen kann. Ich empfand auch die Rechtschreibreform als Zumutung für Menschen, die schon die Schule hinter sich haben, die Umsetzung der Kontonummer zu IBANs ist didaktisch/psychologisch (oft 4-5 Nullen) eine Katastrophe, usw. Darauf folgt: Man muss Menschen nicht mehr vergewaltigen als nötig.

5. Ja, es gibt Diskriminierung! Aber Frauen sind davon als homogene Gruppe im Vergleich wenig betroffen. Überrascht? Ich kann es aber belegen:
   Beruflich stärker diskriminiert ist die Gruppe der Älteren, schon ab 40 wird es schwer, eine neue Anstellung zu finden, ab 50 noch mehr. Beim Verdienst werden die Jüngeren und Berufseinsteiger diskriminiert, das nicht oder kaum bezahlte Praktikum winkt oft statt Festanstellung, oder eben Befristung, etc. Menschen mit ausländisch klingenden Namen finden schwerer eine Anstellung, zumal eine gutbezahlte, desgleichen Wohnungen. Selbständige werden diskriminiert, weil es nicht einmal annähernd rechtssichere Kriterien gibt, was sie der Willkür Einzelner bei deren Beurteilung ausliefert.
   Ja, es gibt sicher Schwierigkeiten und Diskriminierung rund um das Mutterdasein, insb. alleinerziehende Mütter, Wiedereinstieg, gleiche Chancen im familienverträglichen Teilzeitjob, usw., aber diese betreffen nicht die Gruppe aller Frauen, sondern teilweise Männer auch.

Nehmen wir das Beispiel der Quote für Aufsichtsrätinnen... es handelt sich hier um höchst privilegierte Menschen, die Kandidatinnen könnten z.B. kinderlos sein und damit nicht zur Gruppe der wirklich Benachteiligten zählen, des weiteren zumeist auch vorher sechsstellige Jahreseinkommen, nicht wenige bereits Nutznießer hoher und höchster Familien- oder Elterneinkommen und -vermögen sein- ich finde es reichlich unverständlich, dort, wo es der Mehrheit der Frauen nichts nützt, einzugreifen.

Das zuvor zugegeben ausführlich Genannte hat sehr wohl eine Bedeutung in einer Antwort auf eine Frage zu "Ideen zur Anrede", die auch die Begründung der Frage einbeziehen möchte.

Denn:

Das Alles würde ich auch gerne in einer Anrede im Deutschen ausdrücken können. Eine Utopie:

"Verehrte Bürger!

Ich möchte ausdrücklich anläßlich dieser Bürgerdiskussion über die Fußgängerampel auch die Schülerinnen und Schüler der jetzt seit 130 Jahren bestehenden Alice-Schwarzer-Schule begrüßen, die heute mitstimmen werden, ja die sogar heute jeder zwei Stimmen bekommen, denn es ist ja ihr Schulweg.
...
"

Comment: Die erste Antwort in Zeile 4.

Comment: Ich meine ja. Z.B. in der Aufzählung, aber nicht nur. Und (m)eine Meinung ist Teil einer pluralistischen Gesellschaft. Nicht jeder muss jede Antwort (ganz) lesen, das ist Teil Deiner Freiheit. Ich werde Dir das Lesen aber auch nicht abnehmen können, wenn Du es verstehen MÖCHTEST. Ich bin der Ansicht, dass ich viel zur Beantwortung der Frage beitrage, aber auch zur Begründung der Frage, und dass das zusammengehört. Ich möchte mit meiner Antwort u.a. aufzeigen, dass * sich problemlos angesprochen fühlt, wenn * sich nicht diskriminiert fühlt, also hängt beides zusammen.

Comment: Es ist nach Ideen gefragt. Insbesondere nenne ich abstrakte Eigenschaften einer Anrede, und das ist Teil meiner Antwort. z.B. die missionarische Form, die auf Zwang beruht oder Zwang ausübt. Und ich begründe- und das neben einer gewollten Unterhaltsamkeit ernst gemeint, dass die Betonung sexueller Identität durchaus diskriminierenden Charakter hat, erstens für andere Identitäten, z.B. sexuelle Orientierungen, aber es liegt auch eine Geringschätzung schwerwiegender(er) Diskriminierungen darin.

Comment: ..und wenn sich jemand dem Gesagten anschließen kann: Spread the word!

Comment: Nachtrag: obige Kommentar waren zugehörig zu einer Frage, inwieweit dies eine Antwort sei.

Answer (score 0):

Ich habe da eine revolutionäre Idee:

Wir akzeptieren einfach den Geistesblitz, dass grammatisches und biologisches Genus nicht unbedingt dasselbe ist (genauso wie tatsächliche und wahrgenommene Farbe eines Objekts nicht unbedingt dasselbe ist). Dann können wir die Sprache lassen, wie sie ist, und haben alle Befindlichkeiten bereinigt.

(Ach, das ist schon so? Na, dann ist ja alles gut)