# Vorschläge für männliche Movierung

Tags: gender, gender-neutrality, language-cultivation, reference-request

Der linguistische Feminismus kritisiert seit mehr als 35 Jahren die deutsche Sprache für ihre scheinbar unsystematische und unfaire Geschlechtsmorphologie. Fast alle belebten Substantive können durch das Suffix *+in* als [+weiblich] (und [+Femininum]) markiert werden, insbesondere maskuline, die auf *-er* enden, z.B. *Leser+in* (sog. *Movierung* oder *Motion*). Es gibt hingegen keine regelmäßige Möglichkeit, ein Substantiv als [+männlich] zu markieren, aber es gibt einige Derivationsmorpheme, die ein Wort ins [+Maskulinum] zwingen, z.B. *+ling* mit verhältnismäßig geringer Bedeutungsänderung.
Einige Substantive verfügen über einen gemeinsamen Stamm und geschlechtsabhängige Endungen, z.B. *Zeug+e/+in*.
Substantivierte Adjektive und Partizipien ändern ihr Flexionsverhalten nicht und daher sind die Geschlechter nach bestimmtem Artikel *der/die* nicht zu unterscheiden, nach unbestimmten *ein/eine* hingegen schon, z.B. *Studierend+er/+e*.
Daneben gibt es natürlich Paare (und mit Plural Tripel) aus völlig unterschiedlichen Lexemen, die auch in Komposita auftauchen, z.B. *Kauf+mann/+frau/+leute*.

Im Englischen gibt es bekanntlich fast gar kein Nominalgenus mehr – nur Ausnahmefälle wie *actor / actress* – und im Niederländischen sind Maskulinum und Femininum inzwischen weitgehend formidentisch, also wie in den nordgermanischen Sprachen Skandinaviens zum Utrum zusammengefallen.
Luise Pusch hat schon 1984 (vielleicht als erste hinreichend öffentlich) vorgeschlagen, Maskulinum und Femininum für unspezifische Personenbezeichnungen durch das Neutrum zu ersetzen, also *das Leser, das Zeuge, das Student*, und für spezifische Personen das Geschlecht nur in Artikeln oder anderen Attributen anzuzeigen, also *+in* abzuschaffen, d.h. *der/die Leser, der/die Zeuge, der/die Student*.

Ich weiß, dass es auch andere Vorschläge für systematische – aber natürlich hypothetisch bleibende – Reformen des deutschen Sprachsystems gegeben hat, die analog zu *+in* ein männliches Morphem einführen, z.B. *+on*. Allerdings finde ich dazu praktisch keine konkreten, fundierten Texte abseits von Adhoc-Vorschlägen in Forenkommentaren o.ä. Eine Ausnahme ist [*Die Häsis und die Igelin*](http://pauker.at/VIP/matti/kate_DE/2754), wo weitergehende Änderungen anhand literarischer Texte experimentell umgesetzt wurden.
**Welche systematischen Reformvorschläge gibt es noch?**

Ich möchte hier nicht über Sinn oder Erfolgsaussichten solcher Reformvorhaben diskutieren.

Nachtrag: Das [Lexikographieblog](https://lexikographieblog.wordpress.com/2013/06/04/liebe-leserinnen-leser-sind-naturlich-mitgemeint/) hat das Thema mal diskutiert und dabei auf [Sylvain/Balzer (2008)](https://www.geschlechtsneutral.com/lit/Liminalis-2008-Sylvain-Balzer.pdf) verwiesen (*din Studentnin* „Indefinitum“), was auf mich einen sehr amateurhaften Eindruck macht.

Comment: Dieser Schreiberling schreibt von „verhältnismäßig geringer Bedeutungsänderung“?

Comment: *-rich* ist eine native Möglichkeit, belebte Substantive als [+männlich] zu markieren. Der *Händlerich* wäre zwar sehr komisch, aber eindeutig männlich.

Comment: Oder ~bock: Die Geis, der Geisbock, die Ziege, der Ziegenbock, die Hebamme, der Hebammbock?

Comment: @chirlu _+ling_ wird interessanterweise nur mit _schreiben/Schreiber_ und _dichten/Dichter_ so abwertend verwendet. Ansonsten hat es teilweise eine diminutive oder eine im Nebel der Etymologie völlig intransparente Funktion.

Comment: @Veredomon Es ist eher _+ich_ bzw. _+erich_, da es soweit ich sehe nicht ohne R funktioniert: _Zeuge_ → _*Zeugerich_, _Koch_ → _*Kocherich/Köcherich_

Comment: @Crissov war undeutlich, ich gehe von einem Szenario aus, dass Schreib*er* die Neutralform, Schreib*erin* die weibliche und Schreib*erich* die männliche Form wird. Insofern hast Du recht.

Comment: Vorschlag: Schließen. Begründung: Aufzählung erwünscht. ;)

Comment: "Zeuge" ist zwar als Wort männlich, aber kein hinreichendes Sprachmittel um das Geschlecht des Zeugen zu markieren. Es ist damit nicht anders als Bäcker, Wähler oder Fußgänger. Das Wort ist männlich, die bezeichnete Person geschlechtlich unbestimmt. Das ist empirisch nicht widerlegbar - siehe auch Zeugenschutzprogramm, -stand usw. Für die meisten Wörter auf "ling" gibt es kein Wort ohne die Endung (Zwil, Flücht, Hänf) und auch da wird das Geschlecht des Wortes zwar vorgegeben, aber nicht das der gemeinten Person. Die Frage wirft Geschlecht des Bezeichners und des Bezeichneten durcheinander.

Comment: @userunknown _Zeuge_ dient in der Frage lediglich als Beispiel für Substantive, an die nicht einfach _+in_ angehängt werden kann, sondern die einen gemeinsamen Stamm mit verschiedenen Endungen aufweisen. Ich hatte darauf verzichtet, auch _Arzt/Ärztin_, _Koch/Köchin_ oder _Zauberer/Zauberin_ zu erwähnen, wo der Derivationsstamm (_ärzt+, köch+, zauber+, zeug+_) ebenfalls von der Nennform abweicht. _+ling_ dient lediglich als Beispiel für ein maskulines Derivationsmorphem, während bspw. _+in_ feminin und _+chen/+lein_ neutral ist. Genus und Sexus sind in der Frage klar unterschieden.

Comment: @Crissov Warum kann man denn nicht Zeugich, Ärztich oder Köchich sagen? Alles eine Frage der Gewöhnung. Bei -in haben wir uns ja auch daran gewöhnt, dass es ohne -r- funktioniert.

Comment: JFTR, [„Gendern ändern“](http://gendern-ändern.de) propagiert bspw. _-er_ als geschlechtsneutral/-übergreifend (i.d.R. wohl maskulin), _-er**in**_ als feminin+weiblich, _-er**an**_ als maskulin+männlich und _-er**on**_ als explizit divers (Genus unklar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unter dem Schlagwort [Gendern 2.0](https://www.gendern2-0.de) hat sich 2023 eine Gruppe von Proponenten einer zusätzlichen männlichen und überwiegend auch einer notbinären Movierung zusammengefunden, die u.a. auch von Luise Pusch öffentlich wahrgenommen wird. Es gibt (bisher) keinen gemeinsamen, präferierten Vorschlag zur Reform der Grammatik, aber bspw. eine vergleichende Übersicht in der [Pluspedia](http://de.pluspedia.org/wiki/Gleichgestellte_Movierung), die ich hier verkürzt am Beispiel *Koch* wiedergebe.

| Titel | Quelle | Moveme | Person | weiblich | männlich | nonbinär | Personen | weibliche | männliche | nonbinäre |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Gerechtes Deutsch | [Matthias Behlert 1998](https://www.pauker.at/VIP/Matti/kate_de/2754) | *-in, -is* | **die** Koch | die Köchin | **die** Köch**is** | — | Köche | Köch**inne** | Köch**isse** | — |
| Inverses Gendern | [Josef Gnadl 2018](https://www.bo8h.de/Offtopic/), [Max Neumann 2022](https://dasfotobus.wordpress.com/2022/07/08/gendersonderzeichen-substantivierte-partizipien-und-autismus/) | *-in, -on, -ix* | der Koch | die Köchin | der Köch**on** | **die** Köch**ix** | Köche | Köchinnen | Köch**onnen** | Köch**issen** |
| MO4= (movier gleich) | [Christian Melsa 2021](http://gendern-aendern.de/darum/) | *-in, -an, -on* | der Koch | die Köchin | der Köch**an** | **das** Köch**on** | Köche | Köchinnen | Köch**annen** | Köch**onnen** |
| Klassisch Gendern | [Cyril Robert Brosch 2021](https://www.cyrilbrosch.net/bl/thesen/geschlechtergerechte-sprache), [Bernhard Thiery 2022](https://www.openpetition.de/petition/online/klassisch-gendern-reden-wie-frueher-mit-einem-kleinen-unterschied-3) | *-in, -erich/-ich* | der Koch | die Köchin | der Köch**ich** / Köch**erich** | — | Köche | Köchinnen | Köch**iche** / Köch**eriche** | — |
| Basisneutrales Gendern | [Anka Fiedler/Lüthe 2023](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r-2YCq9r720) | *-in, -un, -an* | **das** Koch | die Köchin | der Köch**un** | **das** Köch**an** | Köche | Köchinnen | Köch**unnen** | Köch**annen** |
| (verworfen) | Anka Fiedler/Lüthe vor 2022? | *-in, -us; -i* | **das** Koch | die Köchin | der Köch**us** | ? | Köche | Köchinnen | Köch**i** | ? |
| (Satire) | [Postillon 2017](https://www.der-postillon.com/2017/11/gleichberechtigung-er.html) | *-in, -er* | der Koch | die Köchin | der Köch**er** / Koch**er** | — | Köche | Köchinnen | Köch**erer** / Koch**erer** | — |
| *Liminalis* | [Cabala de Sylvain & Carsten Balzer 2008](https://www.geschlechtsneutral.com/lit/Liminalis-2008-Sylvain-Balzer.pdf) | *-in, -nin* | der Koch | die Köchin | — | **din** Köch**nin** | Köche | Köchinnen | — | Koch**ninnen** |

Answer (score 2):

Ein sehr umfassender "Reformleitfaden" wurde an der Berliner Humboldt Universität von der *AG Feministisch Sprachhandeln* entwickelt und ist unter http://feministisch-sprachhandeln.org/ zu finden.

Dieser Leitfaden zeigt auch eine Übersicht über bereits existierende Vorschläge "antidiskriminierender Sprachhandlungen" (was als genauerer Ausdruck für "geschlechtsneutrale Sprache" verstanden werden kann):

[image: Überblick]

Insb. die sog. *X-Form* [lädt zur](https://www.freitag.de/autoren/rotebrezel/ich-haenge-nicht-an-der-x-for)  [Häme ein](http://diepresse.com/home/bildung/universitaet/4597788/Geschlechtsneutrale-Sprache_Sehr-geehrtx-Profx), weil sie radikal wirkt und ungewöhnlich klingt. Eine der Ideen davon ist, dass auch die oft verwendete Form "Studentinnen und Studenten" ja nur scheinbar geschlechtsneutral ist, weil die [anderen 56 Geschlechter](http://www.welt.de/kultur/article124899285/Wie-Facebooks-58-Geschlechter-die-Sprache-aendern.html) ausgeschlossen sind.

Lann Hornscheidt - die AG leitendx Professx - [erklärt dazu](http://www.welt.de/kultur/article127502626/Professx-statt-Professor-So-irre-ist-das-nicht.html): "Die X-Form soll deutlich machen: Es gibt noch mehr als Frauen und Männer. Alle Sprachänderungen vorher haben versucht, Frauen sichtbarer zu machen. Das X soll einen Schritt weiter gehen und Geschlechtsvorstellungen durchkreuzen, auch bildlich."

Um auf die eigentliche Frage zurückzukommen: eine explizit männliche Form gibt es dann (soweit ich das richtig verstanden habe) in diesem System gar nicht mehr. Man (sic!) würde wahrscheinlich sagen *männlichx Professx*, falls wirklich explizit ein Mann (in welchem klassischen Sinne auch immer) gemeint ist. Der *Vorschlag für männliche Movierung* wäre also die Formel:

Adjektiv (*männlich*) + x  + *Wortstamm* + x

(Beispiele: *männlichx Arztx, männlichx Fußballspielx* usw.).

Comment: Das kann man ja in geschriebener Form alles machen, aber wie würde man _Studierxs_ aussprechen (und vom Singular _Studierx_ unterscheiden können)?

Comment: Das ist eine gute Antwort, aber leider auf eine andere Frage. Bei der Ausrichtung dieser AG – ich habe deren Leitfaden vor einigen Wochen oberflächlich gelesen – verwundert es auch wenig, dass sie sich nicht um Vorschläge kümmert, wie sie mit der Frage gesucht werden, denn die zementieren die Zweigeschlechtlichkeit und erlauben anderen Geschlechtern bestenfalls, sich in der Form für das unbekannte Geschlecht (Utrum oder – bei Sylvain/Balzer – Indefinitum) wiederzufinden.

Comment: PS: Gestern kam ich zufällig in den „Genuss“ eines Textes, der auf Grundlage dieses Leitfadens formuliert wurde. Der darin mehrmals auftauchende männliche Lehrstuhlinhaber wurde durchaus als _der Professor – er_ bezeichnet.

Comment: @chirlu: Ein "Studieriks", viele "Studierikses". In einem der Links steht, dass *x* wie *iks* ausgesprochen wird.

Comment: @Crissov: In gewisser Weise ist es schon eine Antwort. Die männliche Movierung (wie jede andere auch) wird mittels eines Adjektivs gebildet, weil Mannsein eine Eigenschaft unter vielen ist. In anderer Weise beantwortet es die Frage natürlich nicht, wenn diese quasi ein Suffix sucht.

Comment: @Olaf: Stellt sich mir die Frage, warum man das ganz und gar undeutsche "x" nimmt und nicht mindestens "Studieriks und Studierikes" ausschreibt. Ansonsten freut es mich zu sehen, wie sich die Genderisten untereinander zersplittern, das bindet nämlich Kräfte; und wenn sie sich untereinander über die richtige Form und die richtige Anzahl der Geschlechter streiten, können sie wenigstens keinen Schaden anrichten.

Comment: @Veredomon - im Grunde weist Deine Frage schon auf die offizielle Erklärung für das "x" hin: es soll aufmerken lassen, auffallen, und es soll die bisherigen Formen quasi "durchkreuzen".

Comment: @Olaf Und wie soll dann *xs* ausgesprochen werden? *Ikss* ist ja wohl nur schwer von *iks* zu unterscheiden. Ich hatte die Humboldt Universität für etwas seriöser gehalten...

Comment: Und irgendwann fällt den Genderisten auf, dass bei der A-Form (Tabelle, letzte Zeile) der Posessiv *sein* ist, also männlich, also durch *essens* oder irgendwas ersetzt werden muss – wäre bereit, zehn Euro darauf zu verwetten.

Comment: @idmean - wie wäre *iks's*, so ähnlich wie in *Misses*? Aber wie im letzten Kommentar angesprochen : die Idee ist gar nicht, das geschmeidig zu machen, sondern aufhorchen zu lassen. Besonders hässliche Dinge fallen mehr auf.

Comment: Ich dachte das X wird lediglich als Varibale verwendet, um die Lösung zu beschreiben, ohne konkrete Laute festzulegen.