# Gibt es Vorschläge zur Ersetzung/Abschaffung von Dame/Herr(in)/Frau/Mann/Weib?

Tags: gender, synonym, political-correctness, reference-request, language-cultivation

Eine [Frage zu *Mädchen* und *Fräulein*](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/26639/how-to-refer-to-a-woman-based-on-her-age/26646) bzw. eine Antwort darauf brachte mich (ähnlich wie bei einer vorherigen [Frage zur feministischen Sprachkritik](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/25093/vorschl%C3%A4ge-f%C3%BCr-m%C3%A4nnliche-movierung)) zum Grübeln. In der mir bekannten feministisch-sprachkritischen Literatur werden die geschlechtsbestimmten generischen Personenbezeichnungen im Deutschen und ihr Verhältnis zueinander aus verschiedenen Gründen kritisiert, aber ich kann mich außer der Abschaffung von *Fräulein* nur an eine andere Forderung erinnern: die Gleichbehandlung der Geschlechter, also bspw. *Frauen und Männer* statt *Männer und Mädchen*.

Gab es in den vergangenen ca. 40 Jahren weitere ernstgemeinte **Vorschläge zur Reform geschlechtsbezogener Begriffe**, um die Bezeichnungen (Substantive und Adjektive) symmetrischer und damit gerechter zu machen?

[image: Link]

(Bei Bedarf können Antworten natürlich auch andere lexemische Bezeichnungen berücksichtigen, z.B. *Vater : Mutter, Tochter : Sohn, Bruder : Schwester, Mädchen/Mädel/Maid/Dirn : Junge/Bube/Knabe, Onkel/Oheim : Tante/Muhme, Kusine/Base : Cousin/Vetter*, aber bitte keine Bildungsmuster wie *+er/+(er)in*, *+e/+in*, *+eur/+euse*, *+∅/+ess*.)

### Kritikpunkte

(ohne Anspruch auf Vollständigkeit und ohne Bewertung)

- *Dame*: in Komposita häufig euphemistisch verwendet, z.B. *Bardame, Animierdame*, nicht einsilbig wie der (nativ germanische) Rest; als Spielfigur (Schach, Karten) nicht gleichwertig zum männlichen Pendant (König)

  - *dämlich*: scheinbar verwandt (Volksetymologie), negativ besetzt
  - *(rum-)dameln*:  scheinbar verwandt (Volksetymologie), negativ besetzt
- *Herr*: beschreibt eher sozialen Status als Geschlecht

  - *herrlich*: scheinbar verwandt (Volksetymologie), positiv besetzt
  - *herrisch*: kann seltsam wirken, wenn für Frauen verwendet
  - *herrenlos*: kann seltsam wirken, wenn für „Frauenprodukte“ (Handtasche, Rock, Lippenstift, Tampon, Damenfahrrad, …) verwendet
  - *Herrchen*: keine äquivalente Ableitung für *Herrin*, stattdessen *Frauchen*
  - *Herrin*: ausschließlich für sozialen Status, übliche Derivations-/Markiertheitskritik
- *Leute*: wird teils als umgangssprachlich wahrgenommen, versteckt Geschlecht
- *Frau*: kurz für *Ehefrau*, als Anrede neben *Herr* sonst meist neben *Mann*

  - *fraulich*: kann anders als *männlich* nicht einfach nur das Geschlecht bezeichnen, sondern nur für herausgehobene Attribute, → *fräulich*?
  - *Frauchen*: parallel zu *Herrchen* statt *Männchen* gebildet, obwohl keine Anrede, → *Fräuchen*?
  - *Fräulein*: nicht parallel zu *Männlein* oder *Herrlein*, kein männliches Pendant, über Geschlecht hinausgehende Bedeutung, sozial abwertender Gebrauch
  - *Jungfrau*: kein echtes männliches Pendant (*Jüngling, Junker, Jungkerl*?)
- *Mann*: ähnlich zu und etymologisch verwandt mit *Mensch* und *man*, kurz für *Ehemann*

  - *Männchen*: abseits der Tierwelt vielfach geschlechtslos/-übergeifend verwendet, z.B. *Ampelmännchen, Strichmännchen, Männchen machen*
  - *Männlein*: nicht parallel zu *Fräulein*
  - *männlich*: ?
  - *-männisch*: inkonsequent geschlechtsbezogen in Adjektiven zum Tripel *Frau/Mann/Leute*, z.B. *kaufmännisch, fachmännisch*
  - *Männin*: möglich, aber selten, z.B. *Landsmännin*, *Hauptmännin*, ggf. wenn *-frau* schon anders kosnotiert ist, doch wirkt selbst dann seltsam bis anstößig
  - Pl. *Mann* / *Mannen*: schwierig von *Männer* abzugrenzen, daher kann geschlechtsneutrale/-übergreifende Verwendung seltsam wirken, z.B. *Blaumann, Schneemann, Heiermann, Mannjahr* und …
  - *Mannschaft*: kann vor allem in Verbindung mit *Damen-* oder *Frauen-* seltsam wirken, zumal *Herren-* oder *Männer-* meist impliziert und weggelassen wird
- *Weib*: neutrales Genus, heute nur noch abwertend verwendet, viele geschlechtsspezifische abwertende Komposita wie *Klatschweib, Weibergewäsch*

  - *weiblich*: von *Weib* abgeleitet, damit theoretisch aber nicht praktisch abwertend
  - *weibisch*: abwertend wie das Substantiv
  - *Weibchen*: abwertend wie das Grundwort, zumindest für Menschen

### Verwendung

(ebenfalls ohne Anspruch auf Vollständigkeit)

- *Dame – Herr*: förmlich, z.B. als Anrede ohne Namen (sgDuH), im Sport und bei getrennten Kabinen; X *des Hauses*, aber *Hausherrin*
- *Herr – Herrin*: wenn nicht Geschlecht, sondern sozialer Status bzw. leitende Funktion entscheidend ist, z.B. *Bauherrin*, hingegen *Ratsherrin ≈ Ratsfrau ≈  Ratsdame*, aber nicht **Ratsmann*
- *Herr – Frau*: Anrede mit Name, teils alternativ zu *Herr – Dame* oder *Mann – Frau*

  - *Herrchen – Frauchen*: verantwortliche Bezugsperson von Haustieren
- *Frau – Leute – Mann*: Regelfall für Substantive
- *Mann – Männin*: selten, v.a. wenn analog gebildetes Kompositum auf *-frau* schon mit (abwertender) Bedeutung belegt ist, z.B. *Hauptmännin* wegen *Haupt(ehe)frau*, oder wenn ein verwandtes Derivat zu *mann* gebräuchlich ist, z.B. *Landsmännin* wegen *Landsmannschaft*
- *Mann – Weib*: für Menschen nur noch in *männlich – weiblich*

  - *Männchen – Weibchen*: Fauna
- *Weib – Kerl*: äußerst selten, *Teufels*-X

Comment: »als Spielfigur (Schach, Karten) nicht gleichwertig zum männlichen Pendant (König)« – stimmt. Die Dame ist im Schach stärker als der König, den die anderen immer beschützen müssen. Und im Doppelkopf sind die Damen sogar die höchsten Trümpfe, die Könige bloß unteres Beiwerk; die männlichen Trümpfe sind »nur« Buben. Wie geschlechtergerecht doch das Schafkopf ist: Es gibt nur *Ober* und *Unter.* (Nagut, und Säue, aber das sind ja Viecher, auch wenn sie viel wert sind.) ;)

Comment: @Jan Beim Schach ist sie zwar die stärkste, aber nicht die wichtigste Figur, bei Dame hingegen beides. Es ging allerdings allein um die Bezeichnung, vgl. engl. _King_ und _Queen_. Im französischen Blatt gibt es ja sogar 2 männliche Karten pro Farbe und je nur 1 weibliche; im Skat liegt sie wertmäßig zwischen den beiden, und unterliegt bei Stichen immer dem König.

Comment: @Jan: Zu Spielkarten (Achtung, off-topic!): Das Ur-Kartenblatt sind die Tarot-Karten mit 22 Trümpfen und 56 einfachen Karten in den vier Farben Stab, Kelch, Schwert, Münze. Jede Farbe besteht aus 1 As, 9 Zahlkarten (2 bis 10) und den vier Figurkarten Knappe, Ritter, Dame, König. In den Französischen Karten gibt es keinen Ritter, und aus dem Knappen wurde der Bube. In den Doppeldeutschen Karten fehlt die Dame. Der Knappe ist der Unter und der Ritter der Ober. In beiden Blättern fehlen die 22 Trümpfe, und die Farben sind andere (Franz: Herz, Kreuz, Karo, Pik; DD: Herz, Schelle, Eichel, Blatt)

Comment: Warum dieses Pseudo-Problem bedienen?

Comment: @SchcS Die Frage betrifft die deutsche Sprache. Mit den aufgeführten Kritikpunkten sollte klar sein, warum manche Menschen alternative Wörter sinnvoll finden (sollten). Mich faszinieren solche sprachlichen Asymmetrien und darum interessiert mich auch, wie Menschen, die sich daran stören, sich ein geschlechtergerechteres Sprachsystem vorstellen. Dazu muss ich die Kritik nicht teilen und du auch nicht. Eine Antwort könnte ja durchaus lauten, dass es keine Vorschläge gibt, weil sie alle, die das fordern könnten, nur mit Grabenkämpfen um die beste Kurzschreibweise für Beidnennungen aufhalten.

Comment: Die 7, 8, 9, 10 - das sind 4 zusätzliche, weibliche Karten im franz. Blatt. Das As dagegen ist die gemobbte Minderheit. Dumme Sache, das. :) Man kann nat. auch behaupten selten sei wertvoll und dieser inflationäre Gebrauch des weiblichen daher abwertend. Das Wort 'König' ist übrigens geschlechtsneutral, was die Person, nicht das Wort betrifft. Gängig sind aber, m.W., Darstellungen mit Bart.

Comment: Alter Schwede.  Wer geschlechtsneutrale Sprache haben muss kann ruhig nach Ungarn, Estland oder in die Türkei, in den Iran, Afghanistan, Zentralasien, China, Japan usw ziehen, um zu sehen was für Fortschritte in Sachen Gleichberechtigung sowas bringt.  Es ist völlig Wurst.

Comment: @AdamM.B. [WALS](http://wals.info/combinations/31A_30A#2/25.5/148.5) dürfte allgemein bekannt sein, aber nochmal: mir geht es überhaupt nicht um die Sinnhaftigkeit, die sich auf SX auch kaum beantworten ließe, weil “primary opinion-based” oder “too broad”, sondern darum, wie sich diejenigen, die das als Problem sehen, (aber meinetwegen auch andere, z.B. Conlanger) eine Lösung vorstellen.

Comment: Ja verstehe, kenn Dich so vom Forum und wer Ahnung hat wird so was nicht ernsthaft befürworten. Aber konkret zur Sprachwandlung, sowas wie *Schwatztante* kann man kaum ausrotten, je verpönter desto kräftiger. (Übrigens die Autosuggestfunktion will mir nur *Schwarze Tante* erlauben, also selbst wenn die am weitesten verbreiteten Systeme diese Wörter grundsätzlich ablehnen wird die Gesellschaft nicht irgendwie heil.)

Comment: Die geschlechtsneutralen Sprachen haben immer noch jede Menge Einzelwörter wie *Frau* usw, sind also kein perfektes Vorbild.

Answer (score 4):

Es gibt [sprachfeministische Bestrebungen](http://feministisch-sprachhandeln.org/leitfaden/kapitel7/) *man* durch *mensch* zu ersetzen, eine [ahistorische Forderung](http://www.belleslettres.eu/artikel/genus-gendersprech.php), die auf der [falschen Annahme](http://frauensprache.com/man.htm) beruht, dass das *man* Frauen ausgrenze, unsichtbar mache, benachteilige. Die echte Etymologie des Wortes wird ignoriert um die falsche Forderung aufrecht zu erhalten - insofern kann von [Sprachwissenschaft](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Senta_Tr%C3%B6mel-Pl%C3%B6tz) nicht wirklich gesprochen werden.

Weitergehende [Dogmatiker](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luise_F._Pusch) möchten auch Ersatz für *jemand*, *niemand* u.ä. [etablieren](http://www.xartsplitta.net/category/themensplitta/splittabox-zum-intervenieren/) - die naheliegenden ad-hoc-Lösungen *jemenschd*, *niemenschd* klingen aber vielleicht doch zu albern, *jemand oder jefraud* ist wohl selbst denen, die sich mit [Studierendenwerken](http://maedchenmannschaft.net/stellungnahme-aufgrund-der-ermoeglichung-rassistischer-reproduktionen-bei-mmwird5) anzufreunden entschlossen sind, zu bürokratisch. [Exremere Abseitigkeiten](http://www.focus.de/familie/studium/gender-wahnsinn-sprach-experten-lachen-ueber-mitarbeita-und-doktoxs_id_3791712.html) werden aber nicht mehr entziffert und nur von Insidern verstanden.

Comment: Quellen?  Und evtl. Objektivität?

Comment: @jona: bitte schön.