# Genderneutrale Formulierung im Genitiv

Tags: gender, formality, gender-neutrality

Wir sind gerade dabei, einige Texte genderneutral umzuformulieren. Einer der Sätze lautet:

> Der Beleg wird im Auftrag eines/r Kollegen/in bzw. Vorgesetzten erstellt.

*Vorgesetzten* (im Genitiv) ist schon neutral, aber wie ist es mit dem Teil davor?

Habe mir folgende Sachen überlegt:

- eines*einer
- eines*r
- einer*s
- eine*

bzw.

- Kollege*in
- Kolleg*in

Und wie wäre esm wenn es nicht *eines/einer* sondern *des/der* wäre?

- des*der
- der*s
- des*r
- de*

Comment: D.h., es ist die Frage nach einer hübschen Form? Die gibt es noch nicht. Und "Vorgesetzten" ist auch nicht neutral, weil es nunmal eines Vorgesetzten/einer Vorgesetzten im Artikel mitbringt. So bleibt nur "einheitliches Schema auswählen" (gibt da so einige im WWW). "im Auftrag von jemanden aus dem Team/aus der Kollegenschaft" klingt etwas holprig.

Comment: Mit "neutral" meinte ich, dass "Vorgesetzten" selbst ohne Stern auskommt. Die Formen von mir sind aus dem Stegreif, kann ja sein, dass manche davon "richtiger" sind als andere.Suche in erster Linie also eine "richtige" Form, sofern es eine gibt.

Comment: wiki sagt: nö. https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geschlechtergerechte_Sprache German.SE sagt einiges, u.a. dieses: https://german.stackexchange.com/q/2370/36160 (ich teile nicht per se die Antworten, nur die Beispielfrage)

Comment: _"Suche in erster Linie also eine "richtige" Form, sofern es eine gibt."_ Nein, die gibt es nicht. Bislang gibt es keinerlei standardisierten Regeln für eine genderneutrale Schreibweise, sondern nur endlose Diskussionen, und diese wollen wir hier vermeiden. Ich habe für das Schliessen der Frage gestimmt, da man hier nicht mehr als persönliche Meinungen erwarten kann.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Na ja. Man könnte beschreiben, was gängig ist. Oder was von bestimmten Institutionen in Form von Richtlinien herausgegeben wurde.

Comment: Ich finde es den Frauen gegenüber sehr unfair, die weibliche Form im genderneutralen Schema "eines*einer" erst als zweites zu nennen  *Sarkasmusmode off* ;-P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Die Suche nach geschlechtergerechter Sprache ist ein Prozeß, der noch nicht abgeschlossen ist. Daher ist es nicht möglich, eine allgemein akzeptierte Lösung anzugeben.

Was man tun kann, ist zu beobachten, welche Lösungen von anderen gewählt wurden, und sich dann für eine von diesen zu entscheiden. Der Rat für deutsche Rechtschreibung hat eine Arbeitsgruppe zum Thema geschlechtergerechte Schreibung, welche einen [Bericht](https://www.rechtschreibrat.com/DOX/rfdr_2018-11-28_anlage_3_bericht_ag_geschlechterger_schreibung.pdf) verfaßt hat, der einen Überblick über das Thema gibt.

Dort wird erwähnt, daß der Gebrauch des Gender-Sternchens seit 2015 in der öffentlichen Verwaltung zunimmt. Ich wähle als Beispiel die Stadt Hannover, die [Anfang 2019](https://www.hannover.de/Leben-in-der-Region-Hannover/Verwaltungen-Kommunen/Die-Verwaltung-der-Landeshauptstadt-Hannover/Gleichstellungsbeauf%C2%ADtragte-der-Landeshauptstadt-Hannover/Aktuelles/Neue-Regelung-f%C3%BCr-geschlechtergerechte-Sprache) neue [Empfehlungen](https://www.hannover.de/content/download/756032/18968385/file/Flyer_Geschlechtergerechte_Sprache.pdf) für geschlechtergerechte Sprache veröffentlicht hat, welche für die dortige Verwaltung verbindlich sind.

In diesen Empfehlungen heißt es:

> Verwaltungssprache soll alle Menschen
>   ansprechen. Frauen und Männer und jene,
>   die sich nicht als Frau oder Mann selbst
>   beschreiben. Deshalb sollen zukünftig von der
>   Verwaltung geschlechtsumfassende Formulierungen (z.B. Beschäftigte) verwendet werden.
>   Wenn eine geschlechtsumfassende Formulierung
>   nicht möglich ist, ist der Genderstar
>   (z.B. Antragsteller*innen) zu verwenden.

Laut diesen Richtlinien wäre also zunächst zu prüfen, ob eine geschlechtsumfassende Formulierung möglich ist. Da ich den Kontext der infragestehenden Formulierung nicht kenne, mögen meine Vorschläge unpassend sein; aber ich denke, sie illustrieren das Prinzip.

1. Personalpronomen

   > Der Beleg wird in unserem Auftrag erstellt.
2. Adjektiv

   > Der Beleg wird in kollegialem Auftrag erstellt.

In Bezug auf die Verwendung des "Genderstar" ist der Flyer leider sehr knapp gehalten. Was die Schreibung der Artikel angeht, findet sich folgendes Beispiel:

> der*die Ingenieur*in

Der Kommentar dazu besagt:

> in solchen Fällen wird der
>   Genderstar auch **zwischen den
>   Artikeln** gesetzt (Hervorhebung meine)

Daraus leite ich ab, daß es nach den Regeln der Stadt Hannover heißen muß:

> Der Beleg wird im Auftrag **eines*einer** … erstellt.

Die andere Frage ist die nach der Schreibung des Nomens. Wie wird verfahren, wenn die feminine Form des Nomens nicht einfach durch Anhängen einer Endung entsteht, wie es bei *Ingenieur* – *Ingenieur-in* der Fall ist? Welche der drei folgenden Varianten wäre nach den Regeln der Stadt Hannover die richtige?

> 1. der*die Kollege*Kollegin
>   2. der*die Kollege*in
>   3. der*die Kolleg*in

Die erste Variante wendet die Regel für Artikel auf solche Nomen an. Die dritte Variante entspricht dem Beispiel im Plural, das der Flyer gibt, wo die maskuline Endung entfernt wird und der Stamm *Kolleg-* links des Sternchens steht.

> Liebe Kolleg*innen

Wenn man das Pluralbeispiel als maßgeblich ansieht, müßte es also heißen:

> Der Beleg wird im Auftrag **eines*einer Kolleg*in** erstellt.

Je unschöner man diese Sternchenschreibung findet, um so mehr muß man sich um eine geschlechtsumfassende Formulierung bemühen, die des Sternchens nicht bedarf. Es sei daran erinnert, daß dieses laut den oben zitierten hannoverschen Richtlinien auch nur dann anzuwenden ist, wenn eine andere Lösung nicht möglich ist.

<sup>(Ein Nachteil des Gender-Sternchens ist übrigens, daß der Asterisk in Markdown der Auszeichnung dient und man immer \* schreiben muß.)</sup>

Comment: Downvote dem Haß auf das Thema geschuldet oder einem inhaltlichen Problem der Antwort?

Answer (score 2):

Genderneutral wäre es, den grammatikalisch korrekten Artikel für die verwendeten Wörter zu benutzen und vom biologischen Geschlecht der damit bezeichneten Personen abzusehen.

> Der Beleg wird im Auftrag eines Kollegen bzw. Vorgesetzten erstellt.

Alle Versuche, das biologische Geschlecht explizit zu nennen, sind eben gerade nicht neutral und schließen darüber hinaus diejenigen aus, die sich weder dem männlichen noch dem weiblichen Geschlecht zuordnen lassen.

Der Vorschlag, mittels sogenanntem [*Gendersternchen*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gendersternchen) nun auch nichtbinäre Geschlechtsidentitäten einzubeziehen, ist nichts als ein ungeschickter Versuch, den Unsinn der expliziten Auflistung aller möglichen biologischen Geschlechter beizubehalten, um nicht einzugestehen, dass die ganze Debatte von Anfang an an Absurdität kaum zu überbieten ist.

Comment: Deswegen habe ich gefragt, wie man beim Genitiv sinnvoll das Gendersternchen einbauen kann, um eben alle abzuholen.

Comment: Antwort gelesen? Mit dem Sternchen versuchst du, zwischen zwei biologischen Geschlechtern zu unterscheiden.

Comment: Ähm, nein? `Der typografische Stern soll zum Ausdruck bringen, dass sowohl männliche und weibliche wie auch nichtbinäre Geschlechtsidentitäten einbezogen sind` (https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gendersternchen)

Comment: @olafant  Ich meine auch, dass es bei der Genderbewußtheitssignalisierung (durch Sternchen oder welche andere Grapheme auch immer) genau genommen nicht um ein biologisches Geschlecht geht sondern um ein soziales.

Comment: @Marc Du siehst ja, dass das nicht funktioniert. Daher rührt ja deine Frage. Trotzdem danke für den Hinweis. Ich habe diesbezüglich noch einen Absatz hinzugefügt.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Du hast vermutlich recht. Dann geht es also darum, [was in einer Kultur als typisch für ein bestimmtes Geschlecht angesehen wird](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gender). Das soll dann sprachlich explizit nicht diskriminiert und daher müssen alle Möglichkeiten explizit genannt werden. Das ist schon kein Unsinn mehr, das grenzt an Wahnsinn.

Comment: Wenn die Sternchen eine Konvention ausdrücken sollen, dann kann man die Sprache auch lassen wie sie ist, denn qua Konvention ist "Kollege" schon gender- bzw. geschlechtsneutral. Für "Kollegin" gibt es übrigens keine Konvention, jemanden mit weiblicher Geschlechterrolle zu bezeichnen, sondern die ~in-Form hat immer Personen weiblichen Geschlechts bedeutet. "Kolleginnen oder Kollegen" ist übrigens auch nicht neutral, da "Kollegen" schon neutral ist, es müsste schon "Kolleginnen und männliche Kollegen" heißen.

Answer (score 1):

Hier ist guter Rat vermutlich leider gar nicht möglich. Außer man wird radikal und umschifft den Genitiv zur Gänze (mehr oder weniger elegant):

> Der Beleg wird im Kolleg*innen- bzw. Vorgesetzten-Auftrag erstellt.
>
> Der Beleg wird im Auftrag von Kolleg*innen bzw. Vorgesetzten erstellt.
>
> Kolleg*innen oder Vorgesetzte haben Sie beauftragt, einen Beleg zu erstellen. Sie erledigen dies.

Comment: Wieso ist kein weiterer Stern in Kolleg*inn*en? Wie liest man das vor - mit einer (zwei) Pausen in der Wortmitte? Das ist kein Deutsch, das ist Gemurkse!