# m/w/d (männlich/weiblich/divers)

Tags: word-usage

Vor kurzem sah ich in einem Supermarkt ein Plakat mit dem Text

**Verkäufer (m/w/d) gesucht**

Das "d" konnte ich nicht interpretieren, aber eine Internetrecherche zeigt, dass es für "divers" steht. [Zitat](https://karrierebibel.de/m-w-d-in-stellenanzeigen/):

> In immer mehr Jobbörsen und Stellenanzeigen findet sich die Abkürzung (m/w/d). Die Bedeutung:
> (m/w/d) steht für „männlich/weiblich/divers“. Der Zusatz „d“ für „divers“ ist für intersexuelle Arbeitnehmer gedacht und soll dokumentieren, dass die Bewerberauswahl grundsätzlich geschlechtsneutral erfolgt.
> Hintergrund ist ein Urteil des Bundesverfassungsgerichts (Az 1 BvR 2019/16), das feststellte, dass bisherige, binäre Geschlechtsbezeichnungen (männliche/weiblich) gegen das Persönlichkeitsrecht und das Diskriminierungsverbot verstoßen. Entsprechend seien Gesetzgeber und Unternehmen angewiesen, die Diskriminierung von Intersexuellen zu verhindern. Zum Beispiel indem sie Stellenanzeigen geschlechtsneutraler formulieren und „das dritte Geschlecht“ mit angeben.
> **Achtung:** Die Abkürzung (m/w/d) steht keinesfalls für „männlich/weiß/deutsch“. Manche Rassisten interpretieren sie aber leider so.

Meine Frage:

Müsste man jetzt nicht konsequenterweise statt der mittlerweile gewohnten Wortbildung nach dem Schema **Lehrer:in**, **Lehrer/in** o.ä. etwas anderes (mit eine weiteren gender-Endung) schreiben?

Ist bei Verwendung von "m/w/d" wieder das generische Maskulinum korrekt (z.B. Verkäufer)?

PS. Hier noch einige andere Varianten für geschlechtsneutrale Formulierung von Stellenanzeigen:

[image]

Comment: _"Eigentlich müsste es heutzutage **Verkäufer:in** oder ähnlich heißen."_ Wo steht das? Wenn ich mich recht erinnere, schreibt der Gesetzgeber _divers_ vor.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Was der Gesetzgeber vorschreibt, ist in meiner Frage nachzulesen. Es muss nicht unbedingt "divers" verwendet werden, es gibt auch andere Varianten. Vgl. mein Update. Aber danke für den Kommentar, ich habe versucht, mein Anliegen deutlicher zu machen. Pointiert: Wird man in "offiziellen" Texten künftig statt "Bürger:innen" so etwas wie "Bürger m/w/d" lesen?

Comment: Die Frage ist völlig unklar. Welche Instanz soll denn hier wem was vorschreiben? Und wer kann die Zukunft vorhersagen?

Comment: @DavidVogt Keine Instanz schreibt vor, dass man gendergerechte Sprache verwenden muss -  und trotzdem setzt sie sich immer mehr durch. Also ist die Frage naheliegend, wie jetzt mit dem "d" umgegangen wird. Und wo man früher "Verkäufer(in) gesucht" las, heißt es jetzt "Verkäufer (m/w/d) gesucht". Lebt hier das generische Maskulinum doch wieder auf?

Comment: Hängt das nicht einfach von der persönlichen Vorliebe ab? Geht es um die Gegenwart oder um die Zukunft? Zukunft und Vorliebe wären für mich ein Grund, die Frage als *opinion based* zu schließen. Wenn es um Gegenwart und Praxis ginge, habe ich das Gefühl, dass das hier schon des Öfteren thematisiert wurde.

Comment: https://german.stackexchange.com/a/58972/35111 und die verlinkten Dokumente.

Comment: Übrigens falsche Prämisse, daß Sternchen- und Doppelpunktschreibungen nur m/w erfassen sollen.

Comment: Auch falsche Prämisse, dass Gesetze hier irgendwas vorschreiben würden - Dort steht nur, dass niemand wegen seiner sexuellen Identität/Ausrichtung diskriminiert werden darf. Alles andere ist Interpretation.

Comment: Ich vermute ja, dass die "X (m/w/...)"-Schreibweise ursprünglich aus Bereichen wie der Softwareentwicklung kommt, wo "X" ein englisches, und daher generisches Nomen war ("Data Scientist", "DB Admin"), und man die Genderkürzel dort nur verwendet hat, um explizit zu machen, das X eh explizit generisch verstanden werden soll. Dann könnte es sich über "Zweifelsfälle" Fälle wie "Developer" auf deutsche Bezeichnungen verallgemeinert haben. Ist aber nur eine Hypothese.

Comment: @phipsgabler: Dann google mal Lann Horscheid. Mir stellt sich die Frage, wie man überhaupt weiß, ob mit m/w das biologische Geschlecht oder die Geschlechtsrolle (Gender) ausgedrückt wird/werden soll. Die Sprache hat nur eine Unterscheidung, weil sie geprägt wurde, als man sich das gelegentliche Auseinanderklaffen noch keine Gedanken gemacht hat.

Comment: This question opens a discussion about how German should evolve in the future and is therefore off topic. I vote to close it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ich weiß, das Thema gendergerechte Sprache lässt bei einigen regelmässig die Hutschnur platzen, also ... erstmal tief durchatmen.

> Müsste man jetzt nicht konsequenterweise statt der mittlerweile gewohnten Wortbildung nach dem Schema Lehrer:in, Lehrer/in o.ä. etwas anderes (mit eine weiteren gender-Endung) schreiben?

Das wäre natürlich extrem praktisch und ich glaube auch, dass es dazu irgendwann einmal kommen wird, aber im Moment noch keine entsprechende sprachliche Durchdringung besteht. Es gibt allerdings viele verschiedene Zeichen um alle Geschlechtsformen darzustellen. Am bekanntesten sind dabei. neben dem von dir genannten Doppelpunkt. sicherlich der Gender_gap und das Gender*Sternchen. In deinem Beispiel also

> Lehrer_in
>
> Lehrer*in

Natürlich wäre es auch möglich eine komplette neue Form zu bilden. Also als Beispiel könnte man an die Männliche Form immer ein "s" hängen. In dem Fall also meinetwegen.

> Lehrers

Bekannt ist das im Gegensatz zu den Strichen, Punkten und Sternchen allerdings nicht. Wer es liest (und nicht gerade frisch vom Mond kommt) hat bei den bekannten Alternativen jedoch eine gute Chance zu wissen, was gemeint ist.

Problematisch wird es nur bei einer Sache: der Aussprache. Man erinnere sich nur an die aktuellem Diskussionen über das akustisch leicht abgetrennte "in" in den [Heute-Nachrichten](https://www.genderleicht.de/gendern-im-zdf-petra-gerster/) oder [Talkshows](https://web.de/magazine/politik/politische-talkshows/talk-anne-olaf-scholz-wirft-steuerzahler-praesident-unernsthaftigkeit-34730136).

Im Normalfall wird in [diversen](http://bekanntmachungen.luebeck.de/dokumente/d/1055/download) [Sprachleitfäden](https://www.thueringen.de/mam/th10/gb/endfassung_empfehlungen_gendersensible_sprache_stand_10.06.2016.pdf) für Behörden jedoch empfohlen genderneutral zu formulieren, bzw. eines der bekannten Gap-Zeichen (:_*) zu nutzen. Also, z.B.

a) Genderneutrale Personenbezeichnungen

> Lehrende

b) Genderneutrale Begriffe

> Lehrkraft

c) Gap-Zeichen

> Lehrer:in, Lehrer*in, Lehrer_in

Comment: Ich habe den Eindruck, diese Antwort geht gar nicht so recht auf den konkreten Kontext der Stellenausschreibungen und der (fast nur) dort vorkommenden expliziten Nennung von "(m/w/d)" ein.

Comment: Davon abgesehen lässt die Antwort offenbar weitgehend außer Acht, dass es eben nicht nur um m/w geht, sondern um m/w/d. Das "d" wird z.B. nur bei den Optionen a) und b) abgedeckt, und bei a) auch nur im Plural.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Gerade die Alternativen unter c) sind doch entstanden um mehr als nur m/w abzubilden. Dass a) nur im Plural funktioniert stimmt.

Comment: Aber die Alternativen unter c) listen doch auch nur -in auf, fügen zur männlichen also die weibliche Form hinzu.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper In der Regel wird der Stern und der Doppelpunkt als Zeichen verstanden, diverse Geschlechtsidentitäten mit einzubeziehen. Diese Schreibungen sind gerade als Antwort auf die Kritik am Binnen-I entstanden, dem vorgeworfen wurde, nur eine binäre Geschlechterlogik abzubilden.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach: Wie ich auch in den Kommentaren zu [meiner Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/62818/5999) geantwortet habe, war mir das bislang nicht klar. Danke für den Hinweis. Ich vermute dennoch, dass diese eigentlich beabsichtigte Bedeutung weitläufig unbekannt ist, denn sie geht aus der Schreibweise einfach nicht hervor. Allgemein werden Gender-Gap etc. meinem Eindruck nach einfach als "modernere Schreibweise" an Stelle von "/-in" verstanden.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Es wäre tatsächlich interessant, wie das in der Sprecher\*innengemeinschaft verstanden wird :) Wir können da nur spekulieren.

Comment: "Die Lehrkraft" ist ja genauso zweifelsfrei weiblich, wie "der Lehrer" zweifelsfrei männlich ist. Man kann nur beides bejahen oder beides verneinen - mal so, mal so zu argumentieren ist inkonsequent und eklektizistisch.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Dass  Stern (bzw. Doppelpunkt)  als Zeichen verstanden werden soll, diverse Geschlechtsidentitäten mit einzubeziehen, war auch mir nicht bekannt. Das ist auch erklärungsbedürftig und dürfte an großen Teilen der Deutschsprechenden vorbei gehen. Ohne Erklärung wirkt es ja nur wie eine Variante von VerkäuferIn oder Verkäufer(in).

Comment: Offenbar hat der OP diese Antwort inzwischen als die beste eingestuft - aber was ist denn nun die konkrete Antwort auf die Fragestellung 'Ist bei Verwendung von "m/w/d" wieder das generische Maskulinum korrekt (z.B. Verkäufer)?'? Das fehlt irgendwie [immer noch](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/62815/62818#comment153605_62819).

Answer (score 7):

> Müsste man jetzt nicht konsequenterweise statt der mittlerweile gewohnten Wortbildung nach dem Schema Lehrer:in, Lehrer/in o.ä. etwas anderes (mit eine weiteren gender-Endung) schreiben?

Zunächst ist festzustellen, dass es noch nicht die eine "gewohnte Wortbildung" gibt - wie auch aus dem Umstand ersichtlich wird, dass du selber mehrere Varianten aufzählst. Während die aufgezählten Varianten aber (unabhängig von persönlicher Vorliebe dafür) vermutlich wenigstens verstanden werden, besteht meinem Kenntnisstand nach noch kein abschließender Konsens über eine irgendwie gartete "weitere gender-Endung", die das "divers" repräsentieren würde. Zwar existiert der Vorschlag, dies über einen "Gender Gap" oder ein "Gender-Sternchen" (Unterstrich bzw. Sternchen vor der Endung) auszudrücken, jedoch darf bezweifelt werden, dass die intendierte Bedeutung dieser Schreibweisen weitläufig bekannt ist und richtig verstanden wird. Daher halte ich den Vorschlag schon mal nicht für durchführbar.

Davon abgesehen war aber mein Eindruck über die Hintergründe der genannten Verwendung nochmal ein anderer:

**Das "(m/w/d)" (und vormals "(m/w)") wird überhaupt erst gesetzt, um die unterschiedlichen Formen des Substantivs zu vermeiden.**

Sprich: "(m/w/d)" hinter der Berufsbezeichnung kennzeichnet die Berufsbezeichnung explizit als *generisches* Maskulinum (bzw. ggf. generisches Femininum). Listet man das Substantiv hingegen mitsamt allen Endungen auf, kann man sich, soweit ich weiß, das "(m/w/d)" dahinter sparen, weil die Geschlechtsneutralität der Stellenanzeige bereits durch die unterschiedlichen Formen der Berufsbezeichnung klargestellt wird.

Daher, als direkte Antwort auf deine Frage: **Nein, *konsequent* ist es, die Geschlechtsneutralität in genau einer Form der Berufsbezeichnung auszudrücken - *entweder* durch Endungen *oder* durch hintenangestelltes "(m/w/d)".** Und da die Endungen bislang das "d" nicht allgemeinverständlich hergeben, wird momentan meist die letztgenannte Schreibweise bevorzugt.

Comment: *Und da die Endungen bislang das "d" nicht hergeben, wird momentan meist die letztgenannte Schreibweise bevorzugt.* Die Behauptung ist falsch; die Gender-Gap-Schreibungen (mit Stern, Doppelpunkt, Unterstrich) schließen *d* und keine Zuordnung explizit mit ein.

Comment: @DavidVogt: Wieso, der Gender-Gap hängt doch auch nur ein optionales -in an.

Comment: Nein, sonst hätte man ja bei der Paarform bleiben können (oder alternativ Schreibungen wie *Verkäufer/‑in*. Siehe z.B. https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gender-Gap_(Linguistik).

Comment: @DavidVogt: Interessant. Diese Bedeutung war mir noch nicht bekannt, obwohl mir Gender Gap und Gender-Sternchen etc. als Schreibweisen durchaus seit Jahren geläufig sind. Da diese intendierte Bedeutung aus der Schreibweise gar nicht intuitiv hervorgeht, vermute ich auch, dass "Verkäufer_in" etc. zumeist nur als "modernere Variante" von "Verkäufer/-in" verstanden wird. Letztendlich sind wir damit wieder exakt da, wo wir mit dem generischen Maskulinum auch waren - die *intendierte* Bedeutung geht aus dem Begriff nicht hervor. Danke dennoch für deine Hinweis, ich habe meine Antwort angepasst, ...

Comment: ... und am Fazit ändert sich dadurch freilich nichts, dass es genügt, die Geschlechtsneutralität entweder explizit in Klammern oder implizit durch eine irgendwie geartete Auflistung der unterschiedlich gegenderten Berufsbezeichnungen klarzustellen.

Answer (score 1):

> Müsste man jetzt nicht konsequenterweise statt der mittlerweile gewohnten Wortbildung nach dem Schema *Lehrer:in*, *Lehrer/in* o.ä. etwas anderes (mit einer weiteren Gender-Endung) schreiben?

**Nein**, die Idee hinter dem Gender-Gap in *Lehrer_in* und später *Lehrer*in* oder *Lehrer:in* war ausdrücklich, nicht nur das männliche Geschlecht aus *Lehrer* und das weibliche Geschlecht aus *Lehrerin*, sondern in der durch `_` ausgedrückten Lücke auch alle Geschlechtidentitäten zwischen diesen Polen und jenseits davon abzubilden.

Die Schrägstrichschreibung *Lehrer/in* wird hingegen eher als eine orthographisch inkorrekte Variante der Sparschreibung *Lehrer/-in* angesehen, die wie die Klammerschreibung *Lehrer(in)* oder die Schreibung mit Binnenmajuskel *LehrerIn* eben nur die beiden Formen *Lehrer* und *Lehrerin* kompakter zusammenfasst.

Die Schreibung mit Unterstrich, Sternchen oder Doppelpunkt ist also genau die erfragte Alternative zur Inklusion *diverser* Geschlechter.

> Ist bei Verwendung von "m/w/d" wieder das generische Maskulinum korrekt (z.B. *Verkäufer*)?

**Ja**, dieser Marker steht üblicherweise mit einer generischen Stellen- oder Berufsbezeichnung ohne Movierungssuffix.

Comment: Wenn es nicht so wäre, müsste die Stadt nach einer Bürger:innenmeister:in suchen....